# An UrlGenerationError Occurred when I used Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I installed devise to my Rails application and accessed localhost:3000/login.
However, error occurred as below.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Sessions#new
```

Extracted source is this.

```
     </button>
    <ul class="list-group" id="menu-list">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><%= link_to "test1", :controller => "career", :action => "index" %></li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><%= link_to "test2", :controller => "skill", :action => "index" %></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

And it says
'No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"devise/career"}'

The reason is obvious. 
'devise/' attached to the name of controller, so rails can't find the url.

routes.rb is this.

```
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
```

Please teach me why 'devise/' is attached to controller, and how I remove 'devise/'.

Sorry for my poor English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the gem `devise` provides a mechanism for authentication so if you would like to add more paths (URLs) then you have to recognize URLs in `routes.rb` file.

Regarding your code, You don't have the `career` controller so an error will be raised.

In my opinion, You might generate the new controller instead of using `devise/career` which the intention of `devise` is authorization.

Let's say to generate the `careers` as controller

```
rails g controller careers index
```

then the code will be generated as follows;

1. `app/controllers/careers_controller.rb`
2. In `routes.rb` file there will be `get 'careers/index'`
3. The career views will be generated as well.

You can add more below code to `routes.rb`

```
    resources :careers, only: [:index]
```

So...from you code can be rewritten looks like this;

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><%= link_to "test1", careers_path %></li>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did it. I didn't know resources statement.